# Azure DevOps - Publish pipeline task throwing Http timeout exception

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am getting Http timeout exception while using Azure DevOps - PublishPipelineArtifact task.
This task was working perfect till yesterday morning but suddenly getting error all night after trying for multiple attempts also.
Can someone help please ?

Task used below:

version:1.2.3
Publish File size: Few bytes only

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

Exception:

```
Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage for build #1773

Information, ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 71dd2ca5-fba3-42dc-bcae-5d90c107c066

Information, DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 71dd2ca5-fba3-42dc-bcae-5d90c107c066

Information, 1 files to be processed in 1 groups.

Information, 1 out of 1 files processed (Group: 1/1)

Information, Processed 1 files from /home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage successfully.

Information, Uploading 1 files from: /home/vsts/work/1/s/coverage

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.


Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.

Information, ArtifactHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync: https://vsblobprodsu6weu.vsblob.visualstudio.com/A1b625a1a-423a-4874-bccf-3e37eef5432a/_apis/dedup/nodes/A21A6CD7D48BAA32CF50EB0E9E180F56C7472AC5F075DFD53C4483EA4BB8A88A02 attempt 1/6 failed with TimeoutException: 'The HTTP request timed out after 00:00:50.'

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.

Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 0.3 MB.
```

Comment: What is your region? Do you have still this issue. Yesterday there was an issue with Azure Storage which could impact this https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/205114070 It was fixed today morning.

Comment: Our region UK south

Comment: Issue seems to be solved now. This task is working

Comment: This was the reason. Can you consider accepoting my answer and upvoting it to take off this question of the radar of other SO user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by this [accident](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/205114070) in UK South region. Now is fine.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. It recovered today morning